# selecting next status

Tags: sql

Table struct:

```
id
time (unixtimestamp)
tag  (start,stop,fail,qs etc.)
text
job (unique number which identifies the running order)
```

I've a database which stores some machine status like `start`, `stop`, `fail`, `qs` and so on.

My question is that I would like to list all of the data separated by each status like: `select * from database where status='qs'`.

It works fine but the next step will be to check what is the next status. This is where I'm stuck.

If I got the next status I'd like to subtract the times to get the elapsed time.

Comment: Is there an defined order for your status? Like start = 1, stop = 2 usw.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is to create a separate table for statuses:

```
Table Statuses:
id - auto increment Pk
status_name - string
sort_order - int
```

That way you can put the statuses in order, independent of their name.

In your main table, instead of having the tag field be the string of the status, create a column called status_id that points to status.id (a foreign key).

From there you'll be able to JOIN to the statuses table, and ORDER BY status.sort_order.

Once that is is place, getting the elapsed times between statuses will be much easier but I'll leave that to you or someone else on SO.